# Calculating values for new field using values from another field as values in dictionary?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, dictionary

I am using the ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop 10.5. Im trying to use field calculator to return a max value between other fields in the feature based upon a condition. I am not new to python, but I am new to implementing it in ArcMap.  Using field calculator, it seems as though you can reference that row's value for a particular field by delimiting the field names with '!'. What I would like to do is take the numeric amounts for how many people speak a given language per tract feature and then return a string of the most common language name as long as the language is spoken by at least 5% of the population. An example of a python code that I assumed would work is first having a dictionary with keys as the text string for the language name and dictionary values by referring to that field name with '!'. Then putting this dictionary and a function in the 'Pre-logic Script Code' and then in the field calculator passing in this dictionary into the function to return a string.

**Pre-logic Script Code:**

```
Totals = {'Total':!Estimate__Total_!, 'Total only English':!Estimate__Total____Speak_only_English!, 'Spanish': !Estimate__Total____Spanish_!, 'French Haitian or Cajun' : !Estimate__Total____French__Haitian__or_Cajun_!, 'German' : !Estimate__Total____German_or_other_West_Germanic_languages_!, 'Russian Polish or Other Slavic Languages' : !Estimate__Total____Russian__Polish__or_other_Slavic_languages_!,'Other Indo European Languages': !Estimate__Total____Other_Indo_European_languages_!,'Korean': !Estimate__Total____Korean_!,'Chinese': !Estimate__Total____Chinese__incl__Mandarin__Cantonese__!, 'Vietnames': !Estimate__Total____Vietnamese_!, 'Tagalog':  !Estimate__Total____Tagalog__incl__Filipino__!, 'Asian': !Estimate__Total____Other_Asian_and_Pacific_Island_languages_!, 'Arabic': !Estimate__Total____Arabic_!, 'Other': !Estimate__Total____Other_and_unspecified_languages_!}

 def mostCommon (dic):
    most = 0
    lang = ''
    tot = dic['Total']
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if (v > most) and (v >= (tot *.05)):
            most = v
            lang = k
    if lang == '':
        return 'None'
    else:
        return lang
```

and then in my field calculator box below I simply pass the dictionary into the function

mostCommon(Totals)

However, this gives me a parameter error.

Is there any other way for this to be done in field calculator?

I have also researched using UpdateCursor, but im not quite sure how I can reference a value in a particular field for the row and add it to a dictionary as I have above.